# Show PHP array as JSON format

Tags: php, json

i tried to show php array as json, but it kinda look like not json because the format does not look like json, i already turn array into json with json_encode but still not lookalike a real json, how to exactly turn it into normal json

the array after json_encode:

```
[
    "{\r\n  \"merek\" : \"kawasaki\",\r\n  \"cc\" : \"500\",\r\n  \"harga\" : \"50 JT\"\r\n\r\n}",
    "{\r\n  \"merek\" : \"yamaha\",\r\n  \"cc\" : \"250\",\r\n  \"harga\" : \"15 JT\"\r\n\r\n}",
    "{\r\n  \"merek\" : \"bentley\",\r\n  \"cc\" : \"150\",\r\n  \"harga\" : \"8 JT\"\r\n\r\n}",
    "{\r\n  \"merek\" : \"\",\r\n  \"cc\" : \"\",\r\n  \"harga\" : \"\"\r\n\r\n}"
]
```

php code :

```
    $arrayFormalEducation = [];
    for($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i++) {
      // echo $i;
      $merek = $_POST['food']['merek'];
      $cc = $_POST['food']['cc'];
      $harga = $_POST['food']['harga'];
      // print_r($merek[$i]);

      $dataFormalEducation = <<<DATA
      {
        "merek" : "$merek[$i]",
        "cc" : "$cc[$i]",
        "harga" : "$harga[$i]"
  
      }
      DATA;
      $encode = json_decode($dataFormalEducation);

      array_push($arrayFormalEducation, $dataFormalEducation);

    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    $already = json_encode($arrayFormalEducation);
    echo $already;
```

Comment: That is JSON with each element being again JSON encoded string. So you have double encoding. But that is valid JSON

Comment: But why you create `$dataFormalEducation` as string (that can be not valid JSON depending on data) and then encode it into JSON string and put it to another array _and encode again_? Why not just create one array and encode it at the end?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because output is real JSON and there is no error in code.

Comment: The statement `$dataFormalEducation = <<<DATA ... DATA` is an attempt to generate JSON manually. It is not recommended (and it should not be done this way, anyway). Build the data structure that you need them pass it to `json_encode()` for encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Although your output *is* technically valid JSON in the sense that it's a array of strings), it clearly isn't what you wanted or expected.

It makes no sense to try to manually generate JSON as you're doing now, and then encode it afterwards.

The correct way to do your task is to make a regular PHP array/object and then encode that to JSON using json_encode. That's the best way to ensure you get valid JSON, and obviously avoid the logical flaw here where you're effectively double-encoding it.

(N.B. I see you did try to decode the JSON string you'd generated, but you then never used that later in the code, and it's also completely redundant to decode and then re-encode data like that. And generating JSON manually is liable to be very error-prone in terms of outputting something with a syntax error.)

This should make more sense. I've also made the code a lot less verbose without redundant variables:

```
$arrayFormalEducation = [];

for($i = 0; $i <= $total; $i++) {

  $arrayFormalEducation[] = array(
    "merek" => $_POST['food']['merek'][$i],
    "cc" => $_POST['food']['cc'][$i],
    "harga" => $_POST['food']['harga'][$i]
  );
}

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arrayFormalEducation);
```